# How to assign same values in dictionary to another list of strings

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop

I am trying to convert strings to numbers and then assign same values for same words in another list of strings. Assume I have string A like below. I converted to values using dictionary like the code below. Now I need to assign same values to same string in list B and the output should be like res_B

```
A='hello world how are you doing'` 
res_A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

B=['hello world how', 'hello are' ,'hello', 'hello are you doing']
res_B = [[1,2,3],[1,4],[1],[1,4,5,6]]
```

```
A='hello world how are you doing'
d = {}
res_A = [d.setdefault(word, len(d)+1) for word in A.lower().split()]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# map words from A into indices 1..N
mapping = {k: v for v, k in enumerate(A.split(), 1)}
# find mappings of words in B
B_res = [[mapping[word] for word in s.split()] for s in B]
```

Comment: I changed the mapping into a dict comprehension. It's a bit more readable in this way.

Comment: Of course no error checking here, so don't use in production code. Should at least check if `word` exists in `mapping`.

Answer (score 0):

Using a list comprehension again, and the same dictionary from before:

```
res_B = [
    [d[word] for word in phrase.lower().split()]
    for phrase in B
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a step-by-step and functional way to do it

```py
# Create a lookup dictionary
lookup = {word: index for word, index in zip(A.split(' '), res_A)}

# Map every sentence to be replaced with lookup values per word
res_B = [list(map(lambda x: lookup[x], sentence.split(' '), 
                  sentence)) for sentence in B]
```